# Can I use Firebase in this case?

Tags: android, firebase

Recently I've started working on a personal Android Project some weeks ago, and now I've reached to a point that I will need something to deal with the communication between the Android App and Windows (either to a Software or to a Web Application) on which the Android App will send messages to be displayed on the Software or on the Web App (e.g. a chat).

In this case, the Android App and the Software or the Web App will be using different networks.

My question is, since I've never used Firebase before, can someone tell me if it's viable to use Firebase to deal with these communications between Android and Windows?

Thank you

Comment: yes, note that you'll certainly use the "new" firebase, "cloud firestore".  (not the old  one)   note that **PubNub** may be more ideal for you , its the worlds biggest messaging system for what you describe. try the demos https://www.pubnub.com/developers/demos/codoodler/

Comment: Firebase realtime database can do the trick. might not be the best option, but i know it can get the job done (since we had made a chat app using exactly that)

Comment: Beware of the pricing - if you plan on having more than 1000 users, be ready to shell out money, on a per-user, per-message basis. Be sure to check that.